# not creating the exact link [path]

Tags: php, mysql

I made a search form to get the profile of people whom i search the name with, the form is down here and it works

form file is named `search.php` and output file is `result.php` so literally the way the output link must be shown like
`http://localhost/website/result.php?user=Name` but what i'm getting is `http://localhost/website/result.php`

which causes not to copy the profile link and show it to to others or apparently it doesnt work when i go to the first link [`result.php?user=Name`],
which directs me to `index.php`

search.php

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <center><h3>YGG Live Player Stats</h3></center>
    <h5>Enter Player name :<h5> <br/><br/><input type="text" name="search" size=50 maxlength=50><br/><br/>
    <input type="Submit" name="Search" value="Search">
</form>
```

This is the result.php code down here, in which you could see index.php there is what it is actually taking me when i go to links like this `http://localhost/website/result.php?user=Name`

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
include "koneksi.php";
$query = $koneksi->prepare("SELECT * from `playerdata` where `user` = ?");
$query->execute(array($_POST['search']));
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
    $data = $query->fetch();
?>

//html code here

<?php
}
else
{
    go('index.php', 'Username not found!!!');
}
}
else
{
    header("Location:index.php");
}
?>
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: The values won't be passed in the query string like you say, because the `<form>` is using the 'POST' method. The issue you're experiencing may be due to your SQL being incomplete without binding a value to the `user` field in the `WHERE` clause.. What is the 'koneksi.php' file and variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `method="post"` in the form.

If you want your url to be like `http://localhost/website/result.php?user=Name` then you must change `method="post"` to `method="get"` in search.php and use `$_GET['search']` instead of `$_POST['search']` in result.php.

For more informations: [What is the difference between POST and GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get)

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty basic stuff so you should definitely spend some more time with tutorials.

You are sending your form with `POST` so values will not be visible in `URL`.
To change that simply use `GET` method and every value from form will appear in result `URL`.

Comment: Thanks for the info :]

Answer (score 0):

The values won't be passed in the query string like you say, because the `<form>` is using the 'POST' method. The issue you're experiencing may be due to your SQL being incomplete without binding a value to the user field in the 'WHERE' clause.. I realised 'koneksi.php' must be generating your connection object, so try adding:

```
$koneksi->bind_param("s", $_POST['id']);
```

before executing the query, and remove `array($_POST['search'])` from the execution call.

Comment: Thanks for the info mate :]